# RecyclerView get item position to set item LayoutParams dynamically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating a **RecyclerView** with multiple view types.
In the RecyclerView dataset (mResults), I have multiple items of `TYPE_WEB`.
Each item of this type has a specific view `height`.
My problem is:
In the method `OnCreateViewHolder()`, where I tell the adapter what kind of viewHolder to inflate and where I can apply `LayoutParams` to the view inflated, I can't seem to get the position of the `itemViewHolder` inflated. I need the item position in order to get the relevant height from the object at the specified index in the dataset.
If what I explained wasn't clear, I'll give a short example:
Let's say I have in my data set 3 items of `TYPE_WEB`, at indexes 2,4,7.
Each of them has a unique height.
I need to tell the adapter that if the item is of `TYPE_WEB`, get from the dataset the object at the relevant index, get it's height, and apply to the `LayoutParams`.

My code:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

public static final int TYPE_ARTICLE = 1;
public static final int TYPE_WEB = 2;

private Context mContext;
private MyFragmentManager mListener;
private ArrayList<ItemObjectResult> mResults;
private GeneralUtils mGeneralUtils;

//------------------------------------ Constructor ---------------------------------------------

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<ItemObjectResult> mArticles) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mResults = mArticles;
    this.mListener = (MyFragmentManager) mContext;
    this.mGeneralUtils = new GeneralUtils(mContext);
}

//------------------------------------ Listeners methods ---------------------------------------

@Override //RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View convertView;

    switch (viewType) {

        case TYPE_ARTICLE:
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_main_feed_article, parent, false);
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams articleLp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mGeneralUtils.dpToPx(280));
            convertView.setLayoutParams(articleLp);
            return new ArticleViewHolder(convertView);


        case TYPE_WEB:
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_main_feed_web, parent, false);

            /** Get the height of this TYPE_WEB item , int viewHeight = mResults.get(itemPosition).getHeight();
                Create new LayoutParams with the height we got from the item
                Apply the height of this specific web item to it's view */

            RecyclerView.LayoutParams webLp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            convertView.setLayoutParams(webLp);
            return new WebViewHolder(convertView);

    }
    return null;
}

@Override //RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case TYPE_ARTICLE:
            ArticleViewHolder articleViewHolder = (ArticleViewHolder) holder;
            configureArticleVH(articleViewHolder, position);
            break;

        case TYPE_WEB:
            final WebViewHolder webViewHolder = (WebViewHolder) holder;
            configureWebVH(webViewHolder, position);
            break;
    }

}

@Override //RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    ItemObjectResult article = mResults.get(position);

    if (article.getItemType().equals("ARTICLE"))
        return TYPE_ARTICLE;
    else if (article.getItemType().equals("web"))
        return TYPE_WEB;

   return -1;
}

@Override //RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != mResults ? mResults.size() : 0);
}

//------------------------------------ Helper methods ------------------------------------------

private void configureArticleVH(ArticleViewHolder holder, int position){
    ItemObjectResult item = mResults.get(position);

    holder.url.setText(item.getWapLink());
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(item.getImage()).into(holder.mainImage);
    holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.subtitle.setText(item.getSubtitle());
    holder.time.setText(item.getPubDate());

}

private void configureWebVH(final WebViewHolder holder, int position){

    final ItemObjectResult item = mResults.get(position);

    holder.circularProgressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(new CircularProgressDrawable
            .Builder(mContext)
            .sweepSpeed(1f)
            .style(CircularProgressDrawable.STYLE_ROUNDED)
            .build());

    WebSettings websettings = holder.webView.getSettings();
    websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    holder.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(item.getWvUrl());
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            holder.circularProgressBarContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    holder.webView.loadUrl(item.getWvUrl());
}

//------------------------------------ ViewHolder methods --------------------------------------

class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView title, subtitle, time, url ;
    private ImageView mainImage;

    public ArticleViewHolder(View convertView) {
        super(convertView);
        this.mainImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.articleMainImage);
        this.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.articleTitle);
        this.subtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.articleSubtitle);
        this.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.articleTime);
        this.url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.articleUrl);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 mListener.changeFragment(MyWebViewFragment.newInstance(mContext, url.getText().toString()));
            }
        });
    }

}

class WebViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private WebView webView;
    private CircularProgressBar circularProgressBar;
    private RelativeLayout circularProgressBarContainer;

    public WebViewHolder(View convertView) {
        super(convertView);
        this.webView = (WebView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemWebView);
        circularProgressBar = (CircularProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.circularProgressBar);
        circularProgressBarContainer = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.circularProgressBarContainer);
    }
}
```

Solutions I tried an didn't work:

```
int position = holder.getAdapterPosition(); /** on app startup when the recyclerview is being created for the first time, this method always returns NO_POSITION (-1). */

int position = holder.getLayoutPosition(); /** same result as getAdapterPosition*/
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `getAdapterPosition` method.. This is how your `onCreateViewHolder` will look

```
@Override //RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View convertView;

    switch (viewType) {

        case TYPE_ARTICLE:
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_main_feed_article, parent, false);
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams articleLp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mGeneralUtils.dpToPx(280));
            convertView.setLayoutParams(articleLp);
            return new ArticleViewHolder(convertView);


        case TYPE_WEB:
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_main_feed_web, parent, false);



            RecyclerView.LayoutParams webLp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            WebViewHolder holder  = new WebViewHolder(convertView);
            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            // Get height
            int viewHeight = mResults.get(position).getHeight();

            return holder;

    }
    return null;
}
```

In addition if you're adding/removing items from the recyclerview `getAdapterPosition` may return `RecyclerView.NO_POSITION` so you may need to handle that case

**EDIT**:

You can also use StaggeredGridLayoutManager with span count 1.  It is meant to handle items of varying height so you will not need to manage the height explicitly.  You will need to perform the following changes:

1) Make the root layout of your `row_item.xml` have `layout_height = wrap_content`

2) Assign a staggered layout manager to your recyclerview as follows:

`recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredLayoutManager(1, StaggeredLayoutManager.VERTICAL))`

Comment: tried this method, it always returns NO_POSITION (-1).

Comment: @henenge please check if  `getLayoutPosition` works and if yes then I'll update my answer with an explanation for what's happening

Comment: same result as getAdapterPosition() = NO_POSITION (-1)

Comment: Then I suppose it's because the recycler view has not done a single layout pass by then so it doesn't know how the children are laid out . So its not really possible to access the position at that point

Comment: If there are multiple item with same set of heights then maybe you can try creating different view types specific to each height

Comment: but I need to manage the height for each item individually as the height for each item of TYPE_WEB is different, and the only way to get the item's required hight is from it's object's params.

Comment: Then there's no point in using a recyclerview.. If you need to draw each of those items manually then there cannot be any recycling of views and the recycler view will be useless.

Comment: Any other approach you would recommend?

Comment: why do you explicitly need to set height? `wrap_content` will automatically resize items based on size